# Cannot reinstall kernel from chroot

Tags: boot, apt, kernel, chroot

I accidentally deleted the contents of /boot .

I tried

```
apt-get purge linux-generic linux-image-generic
apt-get install linux-generic linux-image-generic

Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  linux-generic linux-image-generic
0 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to remove and 2 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/4044 B of archives.
After this operation, 24.6 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Selecting previously unselected package linux-image-generic.
(Reading database ... 225808 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../linux-image-generic_4.4.0.59.62_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-image-generic (4.4.0.59.62) ...
Selecting previously unselected package linux-generic.
Preparing to unpack .../linux-generic_4.4.0.59.62_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-generic (4.4.0.59.62) ...
Setting up linux-image-generic (4.4.0.59.62) ...
Setting up linux-generic (4.4.0.59.62) ...
```

from a chroot. There were no errors or warnings, but /boot only has the initrd.img and grub (which I did manage to install with apt):

```
ls /boot
grub  initrd.img-4.4.0-31-generic  initrd.img-4.4.0-59-generic  initrd.img-4.4.0-59-generic.old-dkms
```

No vmlinuz!

Why is apt not installing the kernel?

Where can I get the kernel?

**EDIT**

A quick look shows that the linux-image-generic_4.4.0.59.62_amd64.deb does not contain a kernel. Only a copyright and changelog.gz

**What package contains the kernel?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The kernel package is already installed - you damaged it. Reinstall it.

```
sudo apt install --reinstall linux-image-4.4.0-59-generic linux-image-extra-4.4.0-59-generic.
```

Note the difference in names:

The 'linux-image' and 'linux-image-extra' packages are the actual kernel images.

The 'linux-image-generic' package is merely a metapackage that refers to the current kernel image packages...so updates work.

Comment: I figured that a package with a specific kernel version might have a kernel. And that purge would get rid of the actual package.